How to set the pro file in order to debug a Qt programs in release mode using g++ compiler?
I am using Qt Creator on Ubuntu, and compiling my Qt program using g++.
How do I set up my .pro file in order to debug my program in release mode?
I tried to add these lines:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O0 -g
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE =
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O0 -g

But it does not work.

Those arguments add debugging symbols and disable optimisation. Common options are -O2 and -s to strip any symbols.

Please be specific. Don't just say "But it does not work."  The -g is what adds debug symbols. So what doesn't work?
